# How do I ignore data if it doesn't exist in an API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I make this call but the pokemon I've entered doesn't have a second type I get this error message:

[image]

Is it possible to make an `if` statement within the `useState` hook that I've named `setPokemon`?

If so, how can I do that or how can I get through this?

```
 import Axios from "axios";
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./SearchPokemon.css";

function PK() {
  const api = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/",
  });

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});
  const [pokemonDescription, fetchDescription] = useState({});
  const [evolution, pokemonEvolution] = useState({});

  const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/charmander`).then((response) => {
      setPokemon({
        name: response.data.name,
        height: response.data.height,
        weight: response.data.weight,
        img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
        id: response.data.id,
        type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
        type2: response.data.types[1].type.name,
      });

      api.get(`pokemon-species/${response.data.id}/`).then((response) => {
        fetchDescription({
          entry: response.data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text,
          evolution: response.data.evolution_chain.url,
        });
        api.get(`${response.data.evolution_chain.url}`).then((response) => {
          pokemonEvolution({
            evolution: response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name,
          });
        });
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">
        <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{pokemon.name}</h1>
        <h1>No. {pokemon.id}</h1>
        <img src={pokemon.img} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className="info">
        <h3 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
          Type: {pokemon.type} {pokemon.type2}
        </h3>
        <h3>Height: {pokemon.height * 10} Cm</h3>
        <h3>Weight: {pokemon.weight / 10} Kg</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="desc">
        <div className="desc-info">
          <h3 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
            {pokemonDescription.entry}
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        Evolution: {evolution.evolution}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={searchPokemon}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default PK;
```

Comment: What value do you want to assign to type2 if  `response.data.types[1].type` is undefined? null or empty string or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If we first look at your error, the index 1 of your **types** array from your api response data is not defined. Therefore, when you try to access, it throws.

When you are not certain of the response of your api, you can use a combination of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and setting default values for that property.
This way, your code won’t break.

In your example, I believe you could do something like:

```js
const response = {
  data: {
    types: []
  }
};

console.log(response.data.types[1]?.type.name ?? "pick a value or leave an empty string");

// type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name ?? ""
```

Notice the question mark I’ve added right after the index 1 of your expected types array. This symbol allows for optional chaining.

Then we use [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (??).

Comment: Since OP is probably trying to guard from `undefined` and `null`, it'd be more expressive and closer to the code's intent if nullish coalescing (`??`) is used instead of the OR operator

Comment: Thanks Andrew. True, if we consider 0, '', or NaN as valid values. I'll make the edit

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses, appreciate it a lot!
I tried around a bit and got it working as mentioned with:

type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name,

When I tried searching for this I understand int like it ignores that specific line if it doesn't exist, is that correct?

Can this cause any known bugs?